# Breaking lines on smaller screen

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I am trying to break a line on a certain part, only to be displayed on mobile screens.

What I've accomplished: Either I get a reverse effect where the line is broken on big screens and not on small screens, whether I use `min-width` or `max-width` does not matter, or it just doesn't do anything.

Here's the code I want to edit:

HTML:

```
<p class="text">In this line I would like<br class="brnodisplay"> a break on small screen<span>More info</span></p>
```

CSS:

```
.text {
    transition: all 1s ease;
    text-align: left;
    padding-left: 10%;
}

.text:hover {
    color: #fff;
    background: black;
}

.text span {
    display: block;
    float: right;
    clear: both;
    text-align: right;
    padding-right: 10%;
}
```

Is it even possible to "control" line breaks like this on specific widths/devices? Thank you in advance.

Link:

http://jsfiddle.net/8xddb1h7/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use `min-width` so on large screen (width >= 768px) the `<br>` tag will be removed ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8xddb1h7/3/) - resize the bottom right panel):

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) { 
.brnodisplay {
    display: none;
}
```

btw - no need for `!important`.

Comment: It totally works on fiddle and offline! HOWEVER, I added the given code to my wordpress site and everything looks fine up until I reach given px for the br class. When I do, all of the css styling is removed...What the? Thank you for such a quick response

Comment: The problem is obviously with the wordpress site css. What's the link?

Comment: I've added the br class to the paragraph line under the h3 "Allt-i-ett".

http://beautifiedbyelsa.se/wordpress/behandlingar/

Comment: You forgot to close the media query: `@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) { 
.brnodisplay {
    display: none;
}` - add another `}`

Comment: I can't believe I missed that haha, what a lapse of blindness. Thank you so so much! Incredibly appreciated.